# JMX..get currently-deployed application name

Tags: jmx, weblogic-10.x

We are using weblogic10.3.4 , using JMX ,is it possible to get the application name.?
The current application deployed in weblogic server.
Should i use ApplicationRuntimeMBean

Comment: Get the application name for use within a currently-deployed application?  Otherwise, why not just use the JMX management console?

Comment: Yes....currently-deployed application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you use `ApplicationRuntimeMBean`, you would then be able to get the appliation name *via* the `getApplicationName()` method.

You can find more information about this on [the documentation page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/javadocs_mhome/weblogic/management/runtime/ApplicationRuntimeMBean.html) for the `ApplicationRuntimeMBean` interface... and the entire `weblogic.management.runtime` package documentation, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13945/weblogic/management/runtime/package-summary.html).